# Quiero que el textView ocupe todo el width sin modificar el resto

Tags: android, xml, layout

Necesito que el siguiente código tenga layout y que a su vez el textView ocupe
todo el width pero sin deformar los botones de abajo, los cuales deben de pertenecer a la segunda columna intactos.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente tienes definido para el `TextView` con id `textView3` :

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cambia a:

```
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

para que tome todo el ancho del contenedor padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero ahora hay un problema los botones se mueven a la derecha, lo que debes ahora definir es un span que abarque 4 columnas, para esto ahora utiliza la propiedad **[android:layout_columnSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_columnSpan)**.

> [android:layout_columnSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_columnSpan): El tramo de columna: la diferencia
>   entre los límites derecho e izquierdo que delimitan el grupo de celdas
>   ocupadas por esta vista.

`android:layout_columnSpan="4"`.

De esta forma tu `TextView` abarcara todo el ancho que serían 4 columnas de tu GridLayout y se mostraría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- android:id="@+id/textView6"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/black"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
     android:textSize="28dp"
     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp"
     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```